# Sql Server Reporting Services Web Service access problem from a Silverlight Application

Tags: .net, silverlight, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I hope you can help me with this one... :)

I have a .net application which holds a Silverlight component.

I also have Sql Server 2008 R2 with Reporting Services installed.

The SSRS has been added to the Silverlight App as a Web Service Reference.

The above is all running on one development machine (so no cross domain stuff I think, I'm new to SSRS and Web Services).

The issue im having is - when I call/try to access the SSRS web service .asmx (http://localhost/ReportServer_sql2008r2/ReportService2010.asmx) from the SSRS web service reference class in the Silverlight App, I get the following error message:-

> 'An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI
>   'http://localhost/ReportServer_sql2008r2/ReportService2010.asmx'. This
>   could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way
>   without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is
>   unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the
>   service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows
>   SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by
>   using internal types in the web service proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception
>   for more details.'

My thoughts on the error message - I think the stuff about cross domain policy is irrelevant, as this set up is all on one machine. Other than that I don't know what to look for. I searched on this for 2 days and even started reading about Code Access Security, CAS, but not sure if that is the source of the problem.

Any any thoughts would be much appreciated. If you need more info no problem.

Thanks

Rob

Comment: can you show us a simplified version of the code that is failing?

Answer (score 0):

If this error is happening on the client, it might be relevant to know how you are accessing the SL page. If you are accessing it by domain, ie: http://Mycompanyname.com/, then the "localhost" reference can be considered cross site